# Qt creator crashes after choosing new project

Tags: qt, crash

Qt creator crashes after choosing new project (actually, when I just click on project that is below 3rd one) without errors.
Some times there was internal Ubuntu error where was tag:

> qtcreator crashed with SIGABRT in raise().

Comment: here is console output:

QSpiAccessible::accessibleEvent not handled:  "8008"  obj:  QObject(0x0)  " invalid interface!" 
QSpiAccessible::accessibleEvent not handled:  "8008"  obj:  QObject(0x0)  " invalid interface!" 
QSpiAccessible::accessibleEvent not handled:  "8008"  obj:  QObject(0x0)  " invalid interface!" 
Interface is not valid 
ASSERT failure in : "Got an update for an invalid inteface. Investigate this.", file atspiadaptor.cpp, line 899
Аварийный останов (core dumped)

Comment: Please report bugs to either your Linux distribution or the Qt Project.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to :
http://code.google.com/p/clementine-player/issues/detail?id=1706 
Removing the qt-at-spi package solves the problems (it actually did, for me!)
sudo apt-get remove qt-at-spi

Comment: Brilliant! I had the exact same problem using the CFD post processor paraView and this fixed it! Thanks